# PHPStorm Code Inspection and indirect expressions

Tags: php, phpstorm, php-7

I am working on PHP7 compatibility for our plugin and noticed that when using the following code it runs fine without warnings or errors:

```
foreach ( $form_inputs as $order => $input_field ) {
                    $name = ucwords( str_replace( '_', ' ', $input_field['template'] ) );

                    Give_FFM_Admin_Template::{$input_field['template']}( $count, $name, $input_field );
                    $count ++;
                }
```

Yet, PHPStorm doesn't like the brackets:

[image]

I'm using the following syntax as recommended here: [PHP7 method_exists Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34506185/php7-method-exists-uncaught-error-function-name-must-be-a-string)

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Which language version did you configure? It should be at least PHP 5.4 for that syntax, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to show your errors. Rather, copy and paste them here on StackOverflow as text.